# shell_exec() not executing shell script

Tags: php, bash, shell

I've a `shell_test.php` file in `/var/www/html` folder with this code:

```
<?php
    shell_exec('/var/www/html/config.sh');
?>
```

**config.sh** in the same folder has this code:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo -u root kill -SIGHUP $(cat /var/www/html/mosquitto/mosquitto.pid)
```

- When I run `./config.sh` from folder, it runs.
- When I run command in **config.sh** file directly in terminal, it
  works too.

I've added this into **sudoers** file so that there is no need of password:

```
www-data ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/config.sh
```

The thing is it's working fine when run using terminal in both the mentioned ways. Why is not executing when run in PHP?

Comment: how do you know it doesn't run?

Comment: @imox It isn't outputting anything but my mosquitto broker is resetting every time it runs which lets me know.

Comment: `sudo` requires a tty by default. Run your script with `> /tmp/mylog 2>&1` to have it write a diagnostics log to a file

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably, that it is apache, www-data or some other user that is running your script and you try to run it as root.

Try without sudo -u root and change the group of the file to www-data with:

chown root:www-data your-script

Comment: Yes, that would be expected. The user running apache is www-data, so all scripts run by apache is also www-data

Answer (score 0):

As you say "It isn't outputting anything but my mosquitto broker is resetting every time it runs which lets me know"

I think you should replace

```
shell_exec('/var/www/html/config.sh');
```

with

```
$output = shell_exec('/var/www/html/config.sh');
echo $output;
```

According to php docs "shell_exec — Execute command via shell and return the complete output as a string"

shell_exec doesn't print by default; you have to store the string output and then use it

Comment: try exec() maybe

Comment: I tried exec() and system() both. Nothing is happening.

Answer (score 0):

I made few changes in codes and it worked.

In `shell_test.php`, I changed code like this:

```
<?php
    shell_exec('sudo -S ./config.sh');
?>
```

In `config.sh`, I changed like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo kill -SIGHUP $(cat /var/www/html/mosquitto/mosquitto.pid)
```